# choosing which function to run in an onchange depending on other onchange function

Tags: javascript, html, function, onchange

I kind of understand from another post I posted an hour ago but this is what I have:

```
<SELECT NAME="bodyfitting" onChange="updateForBodyfittingnew(); updateForBodyfitting()">
```

So now when the page loads it runs a function called: "UpdateDivision()
The updateForBodyfitting() above should be the one changing for Onchange event.

Now if an onchange event occurs for the division then "UpdateNewDivision() should occur and
The updateforBodyfittingnew() above should be the one changing for Onchange event.  I'm stil not sure how to put this?  I'm sorry I'm not too versed in javascript and HTML.

Comment: So ... what is the question?

Comment: I'm still not sure how to put this?  I don't know how to put it in code.  Like I said I'm not versed that well in this.  There are 2 functions in Onchange for bodyfitting.  One should run "Updateforbodyfitting() if the page loads (UpdateDivision()) and the other "updateforbodyfittingnew() should run if the user makes a change to the division triggering UpdateNewDivision()

Answer (score 0):

Considering your comment (and ignoring your incomprehensible question...no offense), would this work:

(JS)

```
<body onload="Updateforbodyfitting()"> .... </body>

<div onchange="UpdateNewDivision()"></div>
```

(jQuery)

```
$(function() {
    Updateforbodyfitting();
});

$("#SelectedDivision").change(function (e) {
     UpdateNewDivision();
});
```

Comment: hmm, not sure.  Basically when the page loads then updatedivision() should happen, also with this Updateforbodyfitting() loads.  Both of these functions have a dropdown list which the user can change.  If the user changes the division then Updatenewdivision() is fired with the onchange.  This then should generate the new list of values in updateforbodyfittingnew().